# Create an array of numbers between n and m

Tags: kotlin

Hello I'm new to kotlin and I want to create an array of numbers that array.size=4 from 11 to 15 how can i accomplish this task?

```
var array=Array(5){it+1}
```

I don't know how to tell it to start in 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding `1` to `it`, add `11` instead...

```
var array = Array(5) { it + 11 }
```

This works because `it` is the index of the array that the lambda is calculating, starting with `0`. Add `11` to that and you should have `11, 12, 13, 14, 15`, for an array size of 5.

Comment: Thank you so much Todd i will accept the answer once it lets me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @FelipeFranco!